# Gsutil rsync but compress/decompress to Google Drive

Tags: rsync, gsutil

I need to transfer a ton of files from a local Linux folder to a Google Nearline bucket.  Is there some options I can use with gsutil rsync function so that it will compress the files before transferring and then they will be uncompressed on the Google Drive once transferred.

Reason is, I still want to give users access to the files on the Google Drive Nearline bucket via a Samba share that points to the Google Storage FUSE setup on the Linux server connected to the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

`gsutil rsync` doesn't currently support any kind of transcoding such as compression.  Transcoding is not symmetric, so it would be difficult to ensure the behavior was always what the user expected.